# Is this function to compute the factorial in C correct?

Tags: c, function, factorial

I have been reading the book "Hacking - the art of exploitation" (2nd edition, No Starch Press) by Jon Erickson. On page 17, I have stumbled over some code in C of a function that should compute the factorial of a number. I have some programming skills in Python but I am a beginner in C. The code is:

```
int factorial(int x)
{
  int i;
  for(i=1; i < x; i++)
    x *= i;
  return x;
}

int a=5, b;
b = factorial(a);
```

It is written in the book that the variable b will contain 120, since the factorial function will be called with the argument of 5 and will return 120.

Is this correct? As far as I know, x is assigned a new number on every iteration, so the condition i < x is always true. This looks like an infinite for loop to me, but I may be wrong. I have checked the errata on the publisher's website, but I couldn't find information that cleared my question.

If I have made a mistake, can somebody explain me what is wrong? I attach an excerpt of the book for reference.

[image: excerpt from the book]

Comment: No it is not correct. Not sure what the association is between No Starch and O'Reilly, but there is an "unconfirmed errata" on that from 2011 at https://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9781593271442.  No Starch have an errata for the book that does not include that: https://nostarch.com/download/Hacking2_errata_p23.pdf

Comment: In context it is not really relevant.  The author is not attempting to teach C or how to calculate a factorial.  He is providing an example of a function in C, and to that extent it is a syntactically valid function, albeit semantically flawed.  It is at worst an unfortunate distraction from the point the author is attempting to make.

Comment: This show an example of why modifying value parameters in function should be avoided. (That is just my opinion)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct in your observation. The function as written will result in an infinite loop. This is because the condition i < x will always be true as x is being increased in each iteration of the loop (x *= i).

Based on your implementation, I will create another variable to hold the result, like so:

```
int factorial(int x)
{
   int i;
   int result = 1;
   for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
      result *= i;
   return result;
}
int a=5, b;
b = factorial(a); // expected result = 120
```

Comment: `i < x` is not initially true for `x` ≤ 1.

Comment: There is not much point in multiplying by one.  The loop should start at 2.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, this will not work to calculate the factorial. It's also not an infinite loop, since at some point you will get an integer overflow resulting in a negative value for `x`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int x) {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", x);
        x *= i;
    }
    return x;
}

int main() {
    int a = 5, b;
    b = factorial(a);
    printf("%d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5
5
10
30
120
600
3600
25200
201600
1814400
18144000
199584000
-1899959296
```

As you can see, the value of `x` wraps around and becomes negative when it exceeds the maximum positive value in integer can have in C (INT_MAX = 2147483647). Therefore the loop does end, but it definitely won't calculate the factorial.

Comment: The C standard does not define the behavior of integer overflow. It might not necessarily wrap. The optimizer could observe that the condition will never be false for `x` greater than one during the period for which the behavior is defined and replace the code with an infinite loop. Also, `INT_MAX` is not necessarily 2,147,483,647.